Pytorch in GPU is much slower than numpy on CPU？
I've run across the problem that in an MNIST training pytorch GPU method is much slower than merely applying numpy on CPU.
the MNIST data is in the form of csv.
torch method
import os
import time
import torch
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm


def set_gpu(flag):
    if flag:
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            print('>>> Cuda Mod On <<<')
            device = torch.device('cuda:0')
        else:
            print('>>> No Cuda Is Available <<<')
            raise Exception('>>> CUDA is not available <<<')
    else:
        print('>>> CPU Mod On <<<')
        device = torch.device('cpu')
    return device


def load_data(file_name):
    numpy_data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', dtype=np.uint8)
    tensor = torch.from_numpy(numpy_data)
    return tensor, tensor.shape


def brief_processing(tensor):
    result = torch.unique(tensor[:, 0])
    tensor_without_result = tensor[:, 1:]
    tensor_normalized = tensor_without_result / 255
    bias = torch.ones(tensor.size(0), 1)
    tensor_with_bias = torch.cat((tensor_normalized, bias), dim=1)
    tensor_processed = torch.cat((tensor[:, 0].unsqueeze(1), tensor_with_bias), dim=1)
    return tensor_processed, tensor_with_bias.size(1), result


def weight_claim(dims):
    weights = torch.zeros((1, dims))
    return weights


def weight_save(weights, path):
    weights = weights.cpu().numpy()
    np.savetxt(path, weights, delimiter=',')


def BGD_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('BGD Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        p_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
        n_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            p_update_list = []
            n_update_list = []
            for p in p_data:
                x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                    p_update_list.append(x)
            for n in n_data:
                x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                    n_update_list.append(x)
            if not p_update_list and not n_update_list:
                break
            for e in p_update_list:
                w += step * e.t()
            for e in n_update_list:
                w -= step * e.t()
        weight_save(w, f'BGD/{i}.csv')


def SGD_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('SGD Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        p_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
        n_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            for p in p_data:
                x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                    w += step * x.t()
            for n in n_data:
                x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                    w -= step * x.t()
        weight_save(w, f'SGD/{i}.csv')


def batch_create(tensor, batch_size):
    batch = torch.split(tensor, batch_size)
    return batch


def MBGD_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000, batch_size=10):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('MBGD Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        batches = batch_create(tensor, batch_size)
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            for b in batches:
                p_data = b[b[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
                n_data = b[b[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
                p_update_list = []
                n_update_list = []
                for p in p_data:
                    x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                    if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                        p_update_list.append(x)
                for n in n_data:
                    x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                    if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                        n_update_list.append(x)
                if not p_update_list and not n_update_list:
                    break
                for e in p_update_list:
                    w += step * e.t()
                for e in n_update_list:
                    w -= step * e.t()
        weight_save(w, f'MBGD/{i}.csv')


def BGDM_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000, momentum=0.9):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('BGDM Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        v = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
        p_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
        n_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            p_update_list = []
            n_update_list = []
            for p in p_data:
                x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                    p_update_list.append(x)
            for n in n_data:
                x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                    n_update_list.append(x)
            if not p_update_list and not n_update_list:
                break
            g = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
            for e in p_update_list:
                g += e.t()
            for e in n_update_list:
                g -= e.t()
            v = momentum * v + step * g
            w += v
        weight_save(w, f'BGDM/{i}.csv')


def RMSprop_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000, beta=0.9, epsilon=1e-8):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('RMSprop Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        s = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
        p_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
        n_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            p_update_list = []
            n_update_list = []
            for p in p_data:
                x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                    p_update_list.append(x)
            for n in n_data:
                x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                    n_update_list.append(x)
            if not p_update_list and not n_update_list:
                break
            g = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
            for e in p_update_list:
                g += e.t()
            for e in n_update_list:
                g -= e.t()
            s = beta * s + (1 - beta) * g ** 2
            w -= step * g / (torch.sqrt(s) + epsilon)
        weight_save(w, f'RMSprop/{i}.csv')


def Adam_training(tensor, dims, labels, device, step=0.001, max_rounds=1000, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8):
    for i in tqdm(labels, desc=color_desc('Adam Training', 'white'), colour='green'):
        w = weight_claim(dims).to(device)
        m = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
        v = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
        p_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] == i][:, 1:]
        n_data = tensor[tensor[:, 0] != i][:, 1:]
        t = 0
        for epoch in tqdm(range(max_rounds), desc=color_desc('training'), colour='blue'):
            p_update_list = []
            n_update_list = []
            for p in p_data:
                x = p.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() <= 0:
                    p_update_list.append(x)
            for n in n_data:
                x = n.unsqueeze(1)
                if torch.mm(w, x).item() >= 0:
                    n_update_list.append(x)
            if not p_update_list and not n_update_list:
                break
            g = torch.zeros_like(w).to(device)
            for e in p_update_list:
                g += e.t()
            for e in n_update_list:
                g -= e.t()
            t += 1
            m = beta1 * m + (1 - beta1) * g
            v = beta2 * v + (1 - beta2) * g ** 2
            m_hat = m / (1 - beta1 ** t)
            v_hat = v / (1 - beta2 ** t)
            w -= step * m_hat / (torch.sqrt(v_hat) + epsilon)
        weight_save(w, f'Adam/{i}.csv')


def color_desc(desc, color='cyan'):
    color_codes = {
        "red": "\033[31m",
        "green": "\033[32m",
        "yellow": "\033[33m",
        "blue": "\033[34m",
        "magenta": "\033[35m",
        "cyan": "\033[36m",
        "white": "\033[37m"
    }
    reset_code = "\033[0m"
    return f"{color_codes.get(color, '')}{desc}{reset_code}"


def dir_maker():
    dirs = ['BGD', 'SGD', 'MBGD', 'BGDM', 'RMSprop', 'Adam']
    for d in dirs:
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            os.makedirs(d)


def main():
    t0 = time.time()
    device = set_gpu(True)
    path = 'mnist_train.csv'
    data, data_shape = load_data(path)
    data_proc, dims, labels = brief_processing(data)
    data_proc = data_proc.to(device)
    t1 = time.time()
    dir_maker()
    t2 = time.time()
    BGD_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t3 = time.time()
    SGD_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t4 = time.time()
    MBGD_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t5 = time.time()
    BGDM_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t6 = time.time()
    RMSprop_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t7 = time.time()
    Adam_training(data_proc, dims, labels, device)
    t8 = time.time()

    print(f'total time: {t8-t0}\n'
          f'data load: {t1-t0}\n'
          f'BGD: {t3-t2}\n'
          f'SGD: {t4-t3}\n'
          f'MBGD: {t5-t4}\n'
          f'BGDM: {t6-t5}\n'
          f'RMSprop: {t7-t6}\n'
          f'Adam: {t8-t7}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


numpy only
import os
import time
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm


def _load():
    train_path = f'mnist_train.csv'
    test_path = f'mnist_test.csv'
    # the color value is from 0-255 so we apply unit8 as the data type
    T = np.genfromtxt(train_path, delimiter=',', dtype=np.uint8)
    t = np.genfromtxt(test_path, delimiter=',', dtype=np.uint8)
    T= np.hstack((T, np.ones((T.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.uint8)))
    t= np.hstack((t, np.ones((t.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.uint8)))
    dm = len(T[0]) -1
    return T, t, dm

def _classify(ndarray):
    y = ndarray[:, 0]
    y = np.unique(y)
    y = np.sort(y)
    num = dict()
    nnum = dict()
    key = list()
    for i in y:
        num[f'num_{i}'] = ndarray[ndarray[:, 0] == i, 1:]
        nnum[f'num_{i}'] = ndarray[ndarray[:, 0] != i, 1:]
        key.append(f'num_{i}')
    return num, nnum, key

def BGD_training(pos, neg, dm, step=0.001, maxround = 1000,):
    w = np.zeros((1, dm))
    update_list_p = list()
    update_list_n = list()
    for r in tqdm(range(maxround), desc=f"    processing round limited", colour='green'):

        for i in tqdm(pos, desc='      processing the positive'):
            if np.dot(w, i) <= 0:
                update_list_p.append(i)
        for j in tqdm(neg, desc='      processing the negative'):
            if np.dot(w, j) >= 0:
                update_list_n.append(j)

        if not update_list_p and not update_list_n:
            break

        for ii in tqdm(update_list_p, desc='       training false positive'):
            w += step * ii

        for jj in tqdm(update_list_p, desc='       training false negative'):
            w -= step * jj

    return w

def SGD_training(pos, neg, dm, step=0.001, maxround = 1000,):
    w = np.zeros((1, dm))
    update_list_p = list()
    update_list_n = list()
    for r in tqdm(range(maxround), desc=f"    processing round limited", colour='green'):

        for i in tqdm(pos, desc='      processing the positive'):
            if np.dot(w, i) <= 0:
                w += step * i
        for j in tqdm(neg, desc='      processing the negative'):
            if np.dot(w, j) >= 0:
                w -= step * i

    return w

def save_weights(weights, dir):
    # 确保目录存在
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
    for key, weight in weights.items():
        filename = os.path.join(dir, f"{key}.csv")
        np.savetxt(filename, weight, delimiter=',')
        print(f"Saved {key} to {filename}")


def main():
    a1 = time.time()
    T, t, dm = _load()
    num, nnum, key = _classify(T)
    W = dict()
    a2 = time.time()
    print(f'reading data time consumed: {a2 - a1}')

    for i in tqdm(key, desc='                                              processing each number', colour='blue'):
        pos = num[i]
        neg = nnum[i]
        w = SGD_training(pos, neg, dm)
        W[i] = w
    save_weights(W,'BGD')
    a3 = time.time()

    for i in tqdm(key, desc='                                              processing each number', colour='blue'):
        pos = num[i]
        neg = nnum[i]
        w = SGD_training(pos, neg, dm)
        W[i] = w
    save_weights(W, 'SGD')
    a4 = time.time()

    print(f'reading data time consumed: {a2-a1}')
    print(f'BGD learning time consumed: {a3-a2}')
    print(f'SGD learning time consumed: {a4-a3}')
    print(f'total time consumed: {a4-a1}')


main()

when on GPU nvidia 1650 costs over 30h to run BGD&SGD
when on GPU nvidia 4060ti costs over 14h to run BGD&SGD
the torch vision is cu121
when on CPU with numpy:
the time consumption
I wanna know why
I tried different GPU to run the torch code, form 1650 to 4060ti, the speed is improved around 100%, but still very slow.
Of course, I know i should try to measure the loss and break the loop early, but i just wanna figure out why so slow.
after a long while, a result comes as the picture below:
result
and only 12s for MBGD, more confused.

have you tried running torch version on cpu? because transmit data from host (cpu) to cuda also take some time, and maybe your test problem is too simple that the overhead is mostly from data transmission.
